# C# windows forms DataGrid remove empty row at bottom of the grid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagrid, windows-ce

Hi I have a C# windows forms `DataGrid` in my Windows CE application.
The problem is when I bind the Data to the grid it shows an empty row at the bottom of the grid. AS below

[image]

I've read many answers about this and all of them were related to the `DataGridView`. And also in WPF it says to set the following attribute

```
CanUserAddRows="false"
```

And Also they said to change the property

```
AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

But there is no property available like this..
I'm using Visual Studio 2008

This is how I populate the grid

```
DataTable dtAddedItems = new DataTable();
DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            column.AutoIncrement = true;
            column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
            dtAddedItems.Columns.Add(column);
            dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("ItemHeadId");
            dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("ItemName");
            dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("IssuedQty");

            dtgItems.DataSource = dtAddedItems;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Show the code please. how do you set the datasource?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I've updated the question

Comment: If you go to property of `datagridview`, you can find `AllowUserToAddRows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In winforms its: `AllowUserToAddRows = false;`

**EDIT**
*After your edit and comment*

It's a `DataGrid` so from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx)

> You can create a grid that enables users to edit data but prevents them from adding new rows by using a `DataView` as the data source and setting the `AllowNew` property to false.

So with your code it should be:

```
DataTable dtAddedItems = new DataTable();
DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.AutoIncrement = true;
column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
dtAddedItems.Columns.Add(column);
dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("ItemHeadId");
dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("ItemName");
dtAddedItems.Columns.Add("IssuedQty");

DataView dv = dtAddedItems.DefaultView;
dv.AllowNew=false;
dtgItems.DataSource = dv;
```

Comment: There is no property available named AllowUserToAddRows I've updated the question

Comment: what is a DataView?

Comment: See my update and read about DataView: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx